# wifi adapter not found ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

I googled and I installed from github.I tried many methods but it is not working.Every solution is about github duplicate installation but it is not working.this is the name of my driver.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I used this link and this procedure.
1) Get the new wifi drivers from github:

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/

Comment: How can I know which adapater compatible for my laptop?I used because I searched on Internet about wifi driver and I saw some videos on YouTube and everyone is said about this link to install driver. Please help me

Comment: Then please stop running random commands without understanding what they do, this may cause potential breakage. You need to determine your wireless device first. Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`.

Comment: This is the output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list"
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
 Kernel modules: rtl8723be
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no